# How can i promote a pre-release build to production, and have the new version embedded, without a rebuild?

Tags: package, versioning, semantic-versioning, proget

I'm having the same issue as [nuget feeds and promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17735540/556078), eight years later!

In this case I'm talking more generically; we're using ProGet as our package manager, and have nugets, universal packages, and even some docker containers to consider in the package promotion process.

> One of the ideas is to have several Nuget feeds; a ci feed where every successful integration publishes a package, a qa feed that you only publish versions you want qa to test and then a release feed, where you copy only packages from the qa feed that they successfully tested.

So, say we have a build in the `ci` feed that works, it's version `1.2.3-ci-xyz`. We want to promote that to the QA feed, without a rebuild, and re-package it as `1.2.3-rc-1`. That package passes QA and is ready to be promoted into the prod feed, with no rebuild, and ship to production. It should ship as `1.2.3`. (right?)

The question is, if we're not doing any rebuilds, the package binaries will still have the version `1.2.3-ci-xyz`. That'll show up anywhere a version is displayed or queried in the app.

And that's where I get stuck. What's the proper pattern here? Does it matter what version is shipped, as long as we know what it is?

- meaning, we promote `1.2.3-ci-xyz` from lower feeds to higher feeds, without repackaging with different versions?
- Wouldn't it be incorrect for package `1.2.3` to include a binary `1.2.3-ci-xyz`?
- do we always build with the next 3-digit number, and forget about the ci/rc suffix?

Answer (score 1):

I'll share this answer from our internal support channel :)

This is how we (Inedo) typically handle this in our libraries.  The short answer is:

- We set the Assembly Version to Major.Minor.Patch
- We set the Assembly File Version to Major.Minor.Patch.Build
- We set the Package version to Major.Minor.Patch-ci.Build (we then repackage to Major.Minor.Patch-rc.Build then to Major.Minor.Patch)
- We also use the Assemble Informational Version to display a friendly version (ex: Version 6.0.0 (Build 36-v6))

This allows us to repackage without rebuilding. We also will detect these pre-release dependencies during our product builds and prevent them from being released to production.  You can see our ProGet v6 build as an example: [ProGet 6.0.0 Build 36](https://buildmaster.inedo.com/applications/82/builds/build?buildId=8119).

The longer answer I feel is answered pretty well in our blog post [Best Practices for Versioning NuGet Packages in the Enterprise](https://blog.inedo.com/nuget/package-versioning).